# Web Control Panel for KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I need Web Control Panel for KVM that is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 or higher.

SolusVM, Virtualizor isn't compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: You wouldn't be trying to promote a commercial product here, would you? lol Look at this sourceforge project http://sourceforge.net/projects/i-mscp/?source=directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ConVirt** Open Source provides the core functionality for centrally managing your open source KVM or Xen virtualized environment, including monitoring, configuration management, templates-based provisioning, and live migration.

for more information and download check [here](http://www.convirture.com/products_opensource.php)