# New web control panel for KVM Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apache2, php, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

This question was [previously answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416159/web-control-panel-for-kvm). However the answer is outdated, with ConVirt seemingly dead and no simple instructions for other panels.

My setup is Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP 7 running on Apache Web Server.

A lot of packages I see require other operating system's package managers, or come as a complete OS package like Proxmox.

Is there any simple web UI that can be installed on top of Apache, or can be proxied to by Apache whilst it runs on it's own server?

I've tried Kimichi, but it does not run properly on 18.04

Comment: Not that I've heard of, but I'm in the middle of writing one. Stay tuned...

Comment: Do you mean something like webmin, cockpit or phpmyadmin that can run on web interfaces to configure and maintain your server?

Comment: @Terrance No, I use Webmin already, i'm looking for something which can control libvirt and kvm

Comment: What about Kimchi?  https://github.com/kimchi-project/kimchi

Comment: @Terrance Kimichi is extremely unstable on 18.04, requiring modification to install and with some features not working after installation

Comment: Could you please edit your question then stating ones that you have tried and ones that you feel don't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Cockpit has an option to see virtual machines.